# Loop text that wipes left to right using FFMPEG drawtext filter

Tags: ffmpeg

I have the following FFMPEG command which correctly wipes text across the bottom of a video.

```
ffmpeg -y -i test_small.mov -acodec libmp3lame -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -b:a 192k -b:v 1400k -ar 44100 -crf 18 -vf "drawtext=text=string1 string2 string3 string4 string5 string6 string7 :expansion=normal:fontfile=foo.ttf: y=h-line_h-10:x=(5*n): fontcolor=white: fontsize=40: shadowx=2: shadowy=2" -an left_to_right_small.mp4
```

But this only happens once. How do I alter this so that the animation loops with a delay between each loop?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works:

```
-vf "drawtext=text=string1 string2 string3 string4 string5 string6 string7 :expansion=normal:fontfile=foo.ttf: y=h-line_h-10:x=(mod(5*n\,w+tw)-tw): fontcolor=white: fontsize=40: shadowx=2: shadowy=2"
```

See [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rsguhuvoa2) for how it works.

[image: Graph]

*x*-axis is the video width.

*y*-axis is time.

The black line is the width of the image (adjustable in Desmos through a slider, `x`).

The black shade is the text in my formula.

`t` in Desmos corresponds to `tw` in FFmpeg CMD, which is the width of the text.

Blue area is the text in your original formula.

Comment: Thats awesome! How would I set the number of loops?

Comment: @eco_bach It's not as easy as it looks. You can use an [`if`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Expression-Evaluation).

Comment: @eco_bach actually it's doable: `(if(lt(5*n/(w+tw)\,NUMBER_OF_LOOPS)\,mod(5*n\,w+tw)-tw\,w))`. See [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/oldmc7z3nm)

Comment: What does the n stand for inside the mod?

Comment: @RicardoBohner `n` is "the number of input frame, starting from 0". See [doc](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Syntax)

Comment: @Timothy Gu thank you